# Android: Show dialog in front of soft keyboard

Tags: android, dialog, soft-keyboard

I have an EditText and an ImageButton beside it. When I click the EditText the soft keyboard shows up. Fine. When I click the ImageButton a custom dialog shows up and the soft keyboard gets automatically hidden. I want the keyboard to stay open though. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You'd need to make sure the edit field maintained focus, or Android will automatically close the keyboard.  You may be able to do this by manually setting the focus back to the edit field after you pop up the dialog, but it may not work (I'm not sure if another view can be focused if a dialog is up).

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I used the common Dialog class to display my dialog. Using AlertDialog instead did the trick.